# Flask attempting to serialize as JSON despite mimetype=text/plain

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I have an API that I'm posting `application/json` data to that I want to return `text/plain` from. I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable
```

Even though I am *explicitly* setting `text/plain` as the mimetype:

```
return Response(ret_str, mimetype='text/plain')
```

My post looks like this:

```
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json", "Accept":"text/plain"}
r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(data), headers = headers)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Full backtrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 484, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 513, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Can we see more of the backtrace? Nothing jumps out as invalid.

Comment: Also, try using a named arg for the return string, I'm not sure what that positional arg is setting: `return Response(response=ret_str, mimetype='text/plain', status=200)`

Comment: @wholevinski backtrace posted

Comment: So it looks like flask_restful is making the response for you, and their code  only supports JSON out of the box. To extend it, you'll need to follow these instructions: http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/extending.html

Comment: Interesting! But it does work for GET requests...is it just for POST that flask_restful can't handle non-JSON?

Comment: Hm, that is interesting. I'm looking through their code right now and I don't see anything that makes it behave differently for GET vs POST. Check this function out though: https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py#L495 Their docs conflict with the code; you can see that with the `mediatype == 'text/plain'`

Comment: One more thing: Can you try putting a decorator with the content type on it? Like this: `@api.representation('text/plain')` and the one in this example: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#response-formats

Comment: Tried those various things @wholevinksi, nothing has worked thus far. Also opened an issue on the flask-restful repo with no response either. The only thing that "kinda" works is simply returning the raw string not wrapped in a response, but then the endline characters are not rendered properly in the browser (they just appear as "\n").